# How to to get two columns of data unrelated to each other in one sql query statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to get a state level count on number of services. For the purposes of this I only have two services. The first column is the states, the second column is the first services and the third column is the second service. What I am struggling with is to have the second and third column show up on the results in one query. Here is my code:

```
SELECT Distinct allstates.Name, count (data.StateName) as  CareCase_Management_Services, count(data.StateName) Caregiver_Support_Services
From
 (select distinct Name from USstate) allstates
 Left Join
 Client2017 data
 on
 allstates.Name = data.StateName and
 data.FiscalYear = 2017 and 
 data.SrvstartCareCaseMgmtCode NOT IN('999','', '998') and 
 data.SrvstartCaregiverSuppCode NOT IN('999','', '998')
 GROUP BY allstates.Name
 ORDER BY allstates.Name ASC
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and results

Comment: Have you tried to group Client2017 by StateName before joining with "allstates"?

Comment: Client2017 is one table that contains the data that I want and allstates is another table that contains all the statename. So I am not sure I understand your question.   @AdánBucio

Comment: it would make more sense if you showed us what the results should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you are looking to compute, for each state, the count of services that match certain criteria. There are two types of services, stored in two different columns.

If so, your query could be simplified using *conditional aggregation* :

```
SELECT
    allstates.Name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN c.SrvstartCareCaseMgmtCode  NOT IN ('999', '', '998') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) CareCase_Management_Services,
    SUM(CASE WHEN c.SrvstartCaregiverSuppCode NOT IN ('999', '', '998') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Caregiver_Support_Services
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM USstate) s
    LEFT JOIN Client2017 c ON s.Name = c.StateName AND c.FiscalYear = 2017
GROUP BY allstates.Name
```

With this technique, each service is counted according to its own logic ; when conditions are met, the record is counted in (`1` is added to the `SUM()`), else it is ignored (`+ 0`).

NB : do you really have duplicated state names in `USstate` ? if no, you can replace subquery `(SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM USstate) s` with just `USstate`

Comment: That works. Thanks @GMB I also had to remove allstates before.Name

Comment: @Rika I cannot provide samples or results this is highly confidential data